# show hide div doesn't work when radio checked

Tags: jquery, radio-button

any idea why it works perfectly in fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qac6J/1/

and doesn't work if you try it in for example in notepad++

I add head, body, , etc but it still doesn't work

Thanks in advance for help
lukas

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script>

$('.trigger').click(function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).data('rel')).show();
});

</script>

<style>

.content {
display: none;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<form id="group">
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-micro-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-micro-desktop" />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mini-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mini-desktop" />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-maxi-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-maxi-desktop" />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" class="sim-mega-btn trigger" data-rel="sim-mega-desktop" />
</label>
</form>
<div class="billpay-internet-add-ons">
<div class="sim-micro-desktop content">sim-micro</div>
<div class="sim-mini-desktop content">sim-mini</div>
<div class="sim-maxi-desktop content">sim-maxi</div>
<div class="sim-mega-desktop content">sim-mega</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need to add your script in dom ready handler

Comment: Add this before `</body>` - `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>`